# Are there any differences between IE9 final and IE9 RC?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Not trying to solve a problem, just want to have my facts straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of minor differences, but no major platform differences.

See my post on this subject here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/20/ie9-final-release-rtw-minor-changes-list.aspx

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with that link. Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The release notes for IE9 final are here;

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/info/releasenotes/default.html

However they do not provide release notes for the RC, so I guess it will be very difficult to find out.

The following link shows the changes from the beta to the RC. You may find it useful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/11/ie9-release-candidate-minor-changes-list.aspx